# How to divide 3 divs(CSS + MVC)

Tags: c#, html, css

I have 15 charts and i want to show 3 charts per row. It looks like this:

- Chart1 Chart2 Chart3
- Chart4 Chart5 Chart6
- Chart7 Chart8 Chart9

My divs CSS

```
     <div class="one-third">
     <div class="one-third">
     <div class="one-third last">

 for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    if (i != 0 && i % 3 != 0)
    {
        <div class="one-third">
         //chart code 
        </div>
    }
    else if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        <div class="one-third last">
              //chart code      
        </div>
<br />

    }

}
```

But it doesn't look OK. What's the problem with this code?

Comment: What are you doing with this code?

Comment: I am trying to show 15 charts in one page . 3 - 3- 3- 3- 3. i just want to divide them by one-third, one third- one-third last div css.

Comment: something like in my answer?

Comment: Maybe this will be useful http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Comment: @Beamer: there's [not great support for columns yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gice the divs a width / class that has a width, in which only three can fit on (i.e 30% width). That way your browser will only alow 3 on a row anyway:

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  width:30%;
  margin:1%;
  height:100px;
  padding:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition:all 0.8s;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
  line-height:100px;
  }

/**demo only***/

div:hover{
  background:tomato;
  }
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
```

Which could be adapted slightly for nesting as well:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.8s;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}
/**demo only***/

div:hover {
  background: tomato;
}
.nested {
  height: 28%;
  width: 28%;
  padding: 0;
}
.nested:hover {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="nested">1.1</div>
  <div class="nested">1.2</div>
  <div class="nested">1.3</div>
  <div class="nested">1.4</div>
  <div class="nested">1.5</div>
  <div class="nested">1.6</div>
  <div class="nested">1.7</div>
  <div class="nested">1.8</div>
  <div class="nested">1.9</div>
</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
```